# Filter with psql and typeorm

Tags: postgresql, search, filter, psql, typeorm

I need to implement a filter with multiple parameters. For example, it can be a name, city, age, skills and etc. How can I implement it with query builder? Now I use this construction

```sh
      const firstName = params.name
      ? {
          firstName: Like(`%${params.name}%`),
        }
      : {};
    const lastName = params.name
      ? {
          firstName: Like(`%${params.name}%`),
        }
      : {};
    const companyName = params.companyName
      ? { companyName: params.companyName }
      : {};
    const location = params.location
      ? {
          city: params.location,
        }
      : {};

    const searchData = {
      ...firstName,
      ...lastName,
      ...companyName,
      ...location,
    };
     let [users, count] = await this.userRepository.findAndCount({
      where: searchData,
    });
```

But I can't use ILIKE and other stuff. I've tried to use query builder, but I couldn't. Could you help me, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your manipulations with `name`, `firstName`, `lastName` a little confuse me and I'm not fully understand what you want to do,

But query builder approach way could looks like:

```
const { firstName, lastName, companyName, location } = params;
const queryBuilder = this.userRepository.createQueryBuilder('user');

if (firstName) {
  queryBuilder.andWhere(`user.firstName LIKE '%${firstName}%'`);
  // or maybe queryBuilder.andWhere(`user.name LIKE '%${firstName}%'`);
}
if (lastName) {
  queryBuilder.andWhere(`user.lastName LIKE '%${lastName}%'`);
  // or maybe queryBuilder.andWhere(`user.name LIKE '%${lastName}%'`);
}
if (companyName) {
  queryBuilder.andWhere(`user.companyName = ${companyName}`);
}
if (location) {
  queryBuilder.andWhere(`user.city = ${location}`);
}

const [ users, count ] = await queryBuilder.getManyAndCount();
```